# Marcadores de distintos colores desde un csv en leafletjs

Tags: javascript, csv, leaflet

Estoy realizando un proyecto con leafletjs. Tengo la manera acceder a un csv e imprimir los marcadores en el mapa. Lo que no consigo es cambiar el color de esos marcadores, los cuales los extraigo del archivo csv. De manera individual sí, pero lo que me interesa es que sea dinámico.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el plugin: [awesome markers](https://github.com/lvoogdt/Leaflet.awesome-markers), es fácil de usar y te da muchas opciones de colores en los marcadores. Aqui va un ejemplo de como usarlo.
Primero añade en HEAD el siguiente código:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/leaflet.awesome-markers.css">
<script src="dist/leaflet.awesome-markers.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
```

luego este código en BODY:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
<script src="papaparse.js"></script>
<script>
    var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [19.01, -71.22],
        zoom: 8,
    });
    const tileURL = 'https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
    L.tileLayer(tileURL).addTo(map);

    // ejemplos de punto geográficos
    datos = [
        { 'latitud': 19.01, 'longitud': -71.21 },
        { 'latitud': 19.29, 'longitud': -72.10 },
        { 'latitud': 19.05, 'longitud': -71.48 },
        { 'latitud': 19.15, 'longitud': -71.89 },
        { 'latitud': 19.00, 'longitud': -72.11 },
        // adicionar mas puntos geográficos aqui
    ];
    function colorAleatorio () {
        var numeroAleatorio = Math.round(Math.random()*10);
        console.log(numeroAleatorio);
        return numeroAleatorio<3? 'red': 
                numeroAleatorio<6? 'yellow':
                numeroAleatorio<9? 'blue': 'orange';
    };
    for (var j=0; j<datos.length; j++) {
        L.marker([datos[j].latitud, datos[j].longitud], { // creando un marcador
            icon: L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({ // ---> SOLUCION !!!
                prefix: 'fa',       // 'fa' es por usar los iconos de FONTAWESOME
                icon: 'home',       // el nombre de los iconos de FontAwesome
                iconColor: 'white', 
                // se llama a la función para conseguir un color
                markerColor: colorAleatorio(), // simplemente puedes usar 'blue', 'white', 'red', ...
            }),
        }).addTo(map);  
    };
</script>
```

Asi es como queda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]